# Find minimal DNF and CNF of a logical expression $(A \implies C) \wedge \neg (B \wedge C \wedge D).$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I want to find the **minimal CNF** and **DNF** for the following expression: $$(A \implies C) \wedge \neg (B \wedge C \wedge D).$$
I've created a truth table:

\begin{array}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
A & B & C & D & \underbrace{A \implies B}_{E} & \underbrace{\neg (B \wedge C \wedge D)}_{F} & \underbrace{E \wedge F}_{G} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

DNF:
$
     G = (\neg A \wedge \neg B \wedge \neg C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (\neg A \wedge      B \wedge \neg C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (\neg A \wedge \neg B \wedge      C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (\neg A \wedge      B \wedge \neg C \wedge      D)
\vee (\neg A \wedge      B \wedge      C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (     A \wedge      B \wedge      C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (     A \wedge \neg B \wedge \neg C \wedge      D) 
\vee (\neg A \wedge      B \wedge \neg C \wedge      D)
\vee (\neg A \wedge \neg B \wedge      C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (     A \wedge      B \wedge      C \wedge      D)
$

To shorten that, I will simplify the expression by deleting redundant expressions:

$
       G=(\neg A \wedge \neg B \wedge \neg C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (\neg A \wedge      B \wedge \neg C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (\neg A \wedge \neg B \wedge      C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (\neg A \wedge      B \wedge \neg C \wedge      D)
\vee (\neg A \wedge      B \wedge      C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (     A \wedge      B \wedge      C \wedge \neg D)
\vee (     A \wedge \neg B \wedge \neg C \wedge      D)
\vee (     A \wedge      B \wedge      C \wedge      D)
$
$\vdots$
minimal DNF: $\dots$
Same procedure for CNF

CNF:
$G_2=(\neg A \vee B \vee C \vee D) \wedge (\neg A \vee \neg B \vee C \vee D) \wedge \dots \wedge (\neg A \vee \neg B \vee \neg C \vee \neg D)$
$\vdots$

How do I find the minimal CNF and CNF more easily? I could simplify those expressions like I showed above, but this is really time consuming. Is there a way to do this more efficient? If so, could you please explain in detail, how you solved the task?

Comment: For up to 4 variables, and for finding DNF, you probably can't do better than a Karnaugh map. Don't know about CNF, though.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks! How do I create a Karnaugh map to the given expression?

Comment: Recall that $(A\implies C)\equiv(A\lor\neg C).$ The Karnaugh map relies on Gray Code order, so that you're changing as few bits as possible, going from one row or column to the next. Then you can circle maximal sets of True's to get the minimal expression in DNF.

Comment: For DNF, I get $G=(\neg A \land \neg C)\lor(\neg B \land C)\lor(C \land \neg D).$

Comment: Sry for asking stupid questions, but how do I fill in the Karnaugh map? How do I know where to fill in True's and False's?

Comment: @AdrianKeister please read the question above, its important. :)

Comment: The wiki article on K-maps is pretty good. Please refer to that for a more full explanation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: You can use the negation of G plus DeMorgan to get the CNF, by the way.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Cool, I undertand everything now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do my best to type up the K-maps in MathJax. For DNF, you just go with $G$ as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
 AB &00 &01 &11 &10 \\ \hline
CD \\ \hline
00 &1 &1 &0 &0 \\ \hline
01 &1 &1 &0 &0 \\ \hline
11 &1 &0 &0 &1 \\ \hline
10 &1 &1 &1 &1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
From this, we see that $G=(\neg A \land \neg C)\lor(\neg B\land C)\lor(C \land \neg D)$ is the minimal DNF. For CNF, we work with $\neg G$ as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
 AB &00 &01 &11 &10 \\ \hline
CD \\ \hline
00 &0 &0 &1 &1 \\ \hline
01 &0 &0 &1 &1 \\ \hline
11 &0 &1 &1 &0 \\ \hline
10 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
From this, we get that $\neg G=(A\land \neg C)\lor(B\land C\land D),$ and therefore
$G=(\neg A\lor C)\land(\neg B\land \neg C\land \neg D)$ for CNF.

Comment: I tried it by msyself while you were writing this post and came to the same solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> $(A \implies C) \wedge \neg (B \wedge C \wedge D).$
>
> Truth table:
>
> \begin{array}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |} \hline A & B & C & D &
> > \underbrace{A \implies B}_{E} & \underbrace{\neg (B \wedge C \wedge
> D)}_{F} & \underbrace{E \wedge F}_{G} \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
> & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &
> 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
> & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &
> 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
> & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 0 &
> 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 1
> & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 0 & 1 &
> 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
> \end{array}

In order to fill the *Karnaugh Map*, you'll need to search for all the given combinations of "Trues" in your *Truth Table.* Thanks to AdrianKeister for pointing out. Fill in all the gaps and extract the minimal DNF by circling all $2^k$ fields, that contain the number *1*.

Karnaugh map:
\begin{array}{| c | c | c |c | c | c |}\hline
C & C  &  \neg C & \neg C        \\
\hline
\neg D& D &  D & \neg D    \\
\hline
\color{yellow}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & 0 & 0 & \neg B & A\\
\hline
\color{darkorange}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & B &  A\\
\hline
\color{darkorange}{1} & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & B & \neg A \\
\hline
\color{yellow}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \neg B & \neg A\\
\hline
\end{array}
Numbers in similar colors are circled. The color *yellow* should indicate, that two circles are overlapping each other.

The *DNF* is $G=(C \wedge \neg D) \vee (C \wedge \neg B) \vee (\neg A \wedge \neg C)$ or

like *Adrian Keister* already mentioned:

> $G=(\neg A \land \neg C)\lor(\neg B \land C)\lor(C \land \neg D)$

If you want to receive the *CNF*, you will need to mark all $2^k$ fields that contain *0*:

Karnaugh map:
\begin{array}{| c | c | c |c | c | c |}\hline
C & C  & \neg C & \neg C        \\
\hline
\neg D& D &  D & \neg D    \\
\hline
1 & 1 & \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & \neg B & A\\
\hline
1 & \color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & B      & A \\
\hline
1 & \color{red}{0} & 1 & 1 & B & \neg A \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \neg B & \neg A\\
\hline
\end{array}

For *CNF* you will get $G_2=(\neg A \vee C) \wedge (\neg B \wedge C \wedge \neg D)$.